# Pyspark - Passing inequality condition dynamically to dataframes join

Tags: dataframe, join, dynamic, pyspark, inequality

I am using this code from another question: my question is how can I passing an inequality condition here for the join apart from the ON clause.

e.g my join condition is `("ID == ID") & ((DATE1 < DATE2) & (DATE3 > DATE4))`
If my condition was only `ID == ID`, I am able to do that using `list_of_join_columns = ['ID']` but I want to pass the inequality condition as well in the below code: please advise how can that be achieved.

*** existing code *****

```
def join_dataframes(list_of_join_columns, left_df, right_df):
    return left_df.join(right_df, on=list_of_join_columns)

joined_df = functools.reduce(
    functools.partial(join_dataframes, list_of_join_columns), list_of_dataframes,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag dataframe name along with the column in the join condition, in case the column name varies in both the dataframe

Also, it's adviced to rename the right dataframe common column such as id ,

**`right_df = right_df.withColumnRenamed("ID", "right_ID")`**

**`new_df = left_df.join(right_df, (left_df.ID == right_df.right_ID) & ((left_df.DATE1 < right_df.DATE2) & (left_df.DATE3 > right_df.DATE4))`**

Comment: I want to be able to pass the join condition as a parameter just like "list_of_join_columns" is being passed here . Since i want to pass the join column as well as other conditional expression.